# Activity Crashing for seemingly no reason ? -Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Below is my entire activity,
Basically I just pass two intents, send one to a textview, and set the other as the title.
Then I have a toggle fullscreen function down below which works 100%.

I can't seem to figure out the problem. But I did make some major changes recently and after that when I try, the activity can't start and the app crashes.

I have a lot of activities, and I just now found out that Eclipse creates settings_menu layouts for every activity in the menu folder. I don't need to use them except in this one activity.
Say I had like 15 activities total, I deleted 14 of the XML settings menu files of all the other activities except this one (Xtxt).

But after deleting all this, the app still worked. Now I made some changes to the settings stuff, Just the text which appears when you click the menu button.

I can't seem to pin down the problem. So, below is my entire activity, and below that the LogCat output of the error.

```
public class Xtxt extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxtt);
        setContentView(R.layout.xtxt);
        toggleFullscreen(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String svar1 = intent.getExtras().getString("a");
        String svar2 = intent.getExtras().getString("b");
        this.setTitle(svar2);
        textView.setText(svar1);

    }

    private void toggleFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
        if (fullscreen) {
            attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        } else {
            attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }
        getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
    }

}
```

Here's the LogCat:

```
08-19 13:22:20.398: E/ActivityThread(31873): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{x.abcd/x.abcd.Xtxt}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at x.abcd.Xtxt.onCreate(Xtxt.java:27)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
08-19 13:22:20.406: E/AndroidRuntime(31873):    ... 11 more
```

I tried undoing the delete, and even after restoring those deleted menu files I still seem to have this weird Null pointer error. Have I missed something ?

What's wrong ?

Pls help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `setContentView` should come first before initialization of view.

Replace this

```
  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxtt);
  setContentView(R.layout.xtxt);
```

By

```
  setContentView(R.layout.xtxt);
  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxtt);
```

in `onCreate`

You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. Since you have not set the layout to the activity your `findViewById` fails. You are probably getting `NUllPointerException` because of this.

Edit:

It is better to initialize your views in `onCreate` since it is called once during the lifecyle of the activity.

Quoting from the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

`onCreate(Bundle)` is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call `setContentView(int)` with a layout resource defining your UI, and using `findViewById(int)` to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

Comment: could give him a brief explanation on what happens when I invoke setContentView?

Comment: Ahh, yes.. That did it. Stupid me.

Comment: Anyways, one more thing, is it better to initialize components in OnCreate or outside(in the activity block) ?

Comment: @blackbelt thanks for notifying updated and good to see you back on SO

Answer (score 0):

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxtt);
    setContentView(R.layout.xtxt);
```

->

```
    setContentView(R.layout.xtxt); 
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxtt);
```